# Are procedures dealing with customs (as a pilot) off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I was thinking of asking a question regarding customs procedures as it relates to a private flight operation and what they would need to go through in order to legally enter a country in a one-off scenario where they don't have established systems in place with the customs agency (such as a foreign part 129 air-carrier would in the U.S.).

My thoughts are more along the line of an private pilot flying his own plane out to a foreign country for vacation and then returning to his home country.

This could be off-topic and considered more of a travel question?

Would these procedures fall under aviation because it is something pilot-specific regarding customs procedures or would it fall under travel?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what your question is, but it sounds likely to be on topic here. I agree that most questions about customs, documents, visas etc. belong on travel.SE however there are definitely some issues that are unique - or at least different - to private flights.

For example, in the US there are procedural and documentation considerations like eAPIS, required flight plans, required customs decals, required radio licenses etc. I suspect that travel.SE would migrate questions on those things here. Similarly, if someone asked a generic customs question here I'd expect us to migrate it to travel.SE.

But as always on StackExchange, the best thing to do is just ask your question and see what people think.

Comment: I suppose an example could be "Do I need my flight into another country pre-authorized by their customs agency?"

Comment: @RyanMortensen For me that question would be on topic. If you have specific countries in mind it would be good to say so, just to make it more specific and answerable.